# Как сделать плавную смену картинок при наведении на ссылки с помощью jQuery(нужно как-то прикрутить fadeIn/fadeOut)

Tags: jquery

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function l_image(a, b) {
    document.example_img.src = a;
    document.getElementById("link").href = b.href;
  } 
< /script>


<div class="block">
  <div class="block_img">
    <a href="htmls/1.html" id="link">
      <img src="img_hover/1.png" name="example_img" width="130" height="50" id="example_img">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="block_links">
    <a href="htmls/1.html" onMouseOver="l_image('img_hover/1.png',this)">Ссылка №1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="htmls/2.html" onMouseOver="l_image('img_hover/2.png',this)">Ссылка №2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="htmls/3.html" onMouseOver="l_image('img_hover/3.png',this)">Ссылка №3</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```js
var links = $('.block_links').find('a');

links.each(function(){

           var
             $this = $(this),
               src = $this.data('src'),
               img = $('.block_img').find('img'),
               dur = 500;

    $this.on('mouseover', function(){
      img.fadeOut(dur, function(){
  $(this).attr('src', src).fadeIn(dur);
   });
    });
           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_img">
    <a href="htmls/1.html" id="link">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg" name="example_img" width="230" height="150" id="example_img">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="block_links">
    <a href="htmls/1.html"  data-src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">Ссылка №1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="htmls/2.html" data-src="http://rs1054.pbsrc.com/albums/s499/vadimzbanok/1327.jpg~c200">Ссылка №2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="htmls/3.html" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg">Ссылка №3</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Фокус в том, чтобы в "htef" картинки, передавался "htef" наведенной ссылки. А так, за частичный вариант - Спасибо!